# How can I count the nested "tasks" array and groupBy libelle in this scenario?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Now I have this scenario:

I have this array who has a nested array for some profile, but not for all profiles:

```
[
  {
    "id_profile": "1",
    "groupe": "0"
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "2",
    "groupe": "0"
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "3",
    "groupe": "3",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "id_horraire": "765",
        "id_profile": "3",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518937200",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518939000",
        "libelle": "CC-Tech"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "766",
        "id_profile": "3",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518939000",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518940800",
        "libelle": "CC-Tech"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "767",
        "id_profile": "3",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518940800",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518942600",
        "libelle": "CC-Tech"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "768",
        "id_profile": "3",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518942600",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518944400",
        "libelle": "CC-Tech"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "769",
        "id_profile": "3",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518944400",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518946200",
        "libelle": "CC-Tech"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "770",
        "id_profile": "3",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518946200",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518948000",
        "libelle": "CC-Tech"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "4",
    "groupe": "3",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "id_horraire": "771",
        "id_profile": "4",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518937200",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518939000",
        "libelle": "EC1"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "772",
        "id_profile": "4",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518939000",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518940800",
        "libelle": "EC1"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "773",
        "id_profile": "4",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518940800",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518942600",
        "libelle": "EC1"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "774",
        "id_profile": "4",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518942600",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518944400",
        "libelle": "EC1"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "775",
        "id_profile": "4",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518944400",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518946200",
        "libelle": "EC1"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "776",
        "id_profile": "4",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518946200",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518948000",
        "libelle": "EC1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "5",
    "groupe": "3",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "id_horraire": "777",
        "id_profile": "5",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518937200",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518939000",
        "libelle": "EC2"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "778",
        "id_profile": "5",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518939000",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518940800",
        "libelle": "EC2"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "779",
        "id_profile": "5",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518940800",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518942600",
        "libelle": "CC-Tech"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "780",
        "id_profile": "5",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518942600",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518944400",
        "libelle": "CC-Tech"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "6",
    "groupe": "0"
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "7",
    "groupe": "3"
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "8",
    "groupe": "3"
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "9",
    "groupe": "3"
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "10",
    "groupe": "3"
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "14",
    "groupe": "3"
  }]
```

and I want to count for each profile like this:

1. if they have the nested array tasks then

   count how many tasks they have for each 'libelle'

   (example: profile 1 has a **tasks** nested array, and has like this: "2X CC-Tech", "4X EC1")
2. else

   count 0 for other profiles who don't have that nested array.

I can achieve a count directly from DOM calling the profile and then count the `tasks.length` but I cannot separate `libelle`, that will give me a number for total count.

Comment: You have this tagged with both Angular and AngularJS. Which one are you using?

Comment: Any reason why my answer is down voted?

Comment: @R.Richards I don't really know the difference and what I'm using.
Sorry and thanks for your assistance

Comment: @Batman  Thank you for your help, but I don't know who down voted your answer.
However I tried it now and it seems to work. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently What I am doing is , I am using `.forEach` and iterate over the array and If any of these contains I will find the count of objects in the `Tasks` and later I will create the object called `nameobj` and I store the Subjects Names with the count its repeated

```js
var array = [{
    "id_profile": "1",
    "groupe": "0"
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "2",
    "groupe": "0"
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "3",
    "groupe": "3",
    "tasks": [{
        "id_horraire": "765",
        "id_profile": "3",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518937200",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518939000",
        "libelle": "CC-Tech"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "766",
        "id_profile": "3",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518939000",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518940800",
        "libelle": "CC-Tech"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "767",
        "id_profile": "3",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518940800",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518942600",
        "libelle": "CC-Tech"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "768",
        "id_profile": "3",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518942600",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518944400",
        "libelle": "CC-Tech"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "769",
        "id_profile": "3",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518944400",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518946200",
        "libelle": "CC-Tech"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "770",
        "id_profile": "3",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518946200",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518948000",
        "libelle": "CC-Tech"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "4",
    "groupe": "3",
    "tasks": [{
        "id_horraire": "771",
        "id_profile": "4",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518937200",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518939000",
        "libelle": "EC1"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "772",
        "id_profile": "4",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518939000",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518940800",
        "libelle": "EC1"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "773",
        "id_profile": "4",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518940800",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518942600",
        "libelle": "EC1"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "774",
        "id_profile": "4",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518942600",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518944400",
        "libelle": "EC1"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "775",
        "id_profile": "4",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518944400",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518946200",
        "libelle": "EC1"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "776",
        "id_profile": "4",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518946200",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518948000",
        "libelle": "EC1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "5",
    "groupe": "3",
    "tasks": [{
        "id_horraire": "777",
        "id_profile": "5",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518937200",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518939000",
        "libelle": "EC2"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "778",
        "id_profile": "5",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518939000",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518940800",
        "libelle": "EC2"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "779",
        "id_profile": "5",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518940800",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518942600",
        "libelle": "CC-Tech"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "780",
        "id_profile": "5",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518942600",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518944400",
        "libelle": "CC-Tech"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "6",
    "groupe": "0"
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "7",
    "groupe": "3"
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "8",
    "groupe": "3"
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "9",
    "groupe": "3"
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "10",
    "groupe": "3"
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "14",
    "groupe": "3"
  }
];

array.forEach(function(item, index) {
  if (item.tasks) {
    var nameobj = {};
    var count;
    console.log("Number Of Objects in Tasks Array : " + item.tasks.length + " in the Profile : " + item.id_profile);
    item.tasks.forEach(function(task, index) {
      if (!nameobj[task.libelle]) {
        count = 1;
        nameobj[task.libelle] = count;
      } else {
        count = count + 1;
        nameobj[task.libelle] = count;
        //console.log(nameobj[task.libelle]);
      }
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(nameobj));
  }
});
```

Comment: I have gone through that what is the problem here?

Comment: I am answering the question which is asked to the point ,Let me know what to correct here?

Comment: Okay great, Can you please help here to optimize this answer that would be really help me to answer my next questions

Comment: That link contains all you need to know. Add explanation of what you changed in the code and how it helps the OP. Oh, and don't use quote formatting for things that are not quotes.

Comment: Thanks Mike I will change the answer now accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear which one you are using: AngularJS or Angular (2, 4 or 5)?

But I can give you a fair idea how to take out the libelles in JS and push the array of libelles in the current profile.

```
let profiles = [
  {
    "id_profile": "1",
    "groupe": "0"
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "2",
    "groupe": "0"
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "3",
    "groupe": "3",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "id_horraire": "765",
        "id_profile": "3",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518937200",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518939000",
        "libelle": "CC-Tech"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "766",
        "id_profile": "3",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518939000",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518940800",
        "libelle": "CC-Tech"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "767",
        "id_profile": "3",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518940800",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518942600",
        "libelle": "CC-Tech"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "768",
        "id_profile": "3",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518942600",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518944400",
        "libelle": "CC-Tech"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "769",
        "id_profile": "3",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518944400",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518946200",
        "libelle": "CC-Tech"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "770",
        "id_profile": "3",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518946200",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518948000",
        "libelle": "CC-Tech"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "4",
    "groupe": "3",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "id_horraire": "771",
        "id_profile": "4",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518937200",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518939000",
        "libelle": "EC1"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "772",
        "id_profile": "4",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518939000",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518940800",
        "libelle": "EC1"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "773",
        "id_profile": "4",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518940800",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518942600",
        "libelle": "EC1"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "774",
        "id_profile": "4",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518942600",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518944400",
        "libelle": "EC1"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "775",
        "id_profile": "4",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518944400",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518946200",
        "libelle": "EC1"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "776",
        "id_profile": "4",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518946200",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518948000",
        "libelle": "EC1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "5",
    "groupe": "3",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "id_horraire": "777",
        "id_profile": "5",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518937200",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518939000",
        "libelle": "EC2"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "778",
        "id_profile": "5",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518939000",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518940800",
        "libelle": "EC2"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "779",
        "id_profile": "5",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518940800",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518942600",
        "libelle": "CC-Tech"
      },
      {
        "id_horraire": "780",
        "id_profile": "5",
        "date_heure_deb": "1518942600",
        "date_heure_fin": "1518944400",
        "libelle": "CC-Tech"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "6",
    "groupe": "0"
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "7",
    "groupe": "3"
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "8",
    "groupe": "3"
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "9",
    "groupe": "3"
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "10",
    "groupe": "3"
  },
  {
    "id_profile": "14",
    "groupe": "3"
  }];

  function retrieveLibelle() {
  profiles.forEach((profile) => {
     if (profile.hasOwnProperty('tasks')) {
        if (profile.tasks.length > 0) {
           profile.libelles = [];
           profile.tasks.forEach((task) => {
              if (task.hasOwnProperty('libelle')) {
                 profile.libelles.push(task.libelle);
              }
           });
           console.log(profile.libelles);
        }
     } 
  });
  console.log(profiles);
  }

  retrieveLibelle();
```

Now in the DOM, you will have a new array in the `profiles` array named `libelles` for each profile, from which you can calculate the length of all array and also separate all libelles using array's toString() method.